# Javescript create list of numbers 0 to n

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I dont know anything about programming, so bare with me.
I need an expression for a textlayer in adobe after effects which uses javascript. The expression needs to create a customizable list of numbers using 3 variables -
example:

```
x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list)
y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps)
z= 5 //the number of steps
```

the output needs to be a list with each entry in a new line, in this case:

```
0
20
40
60
80
```

Hope somebody can help. Thanks

Comment: a for loop for the no of steps and each step add 20?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for answering questions based on existing code. This should help you https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp though

Comment: Under the assumption that [AdobeAE supports ES2018](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/legacy-and-extend-script-engine.html), here is an **expression** that should satisfy your requirements:  `Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x)`

Comment: @spender It kinda works but the output ist a list in a single line with commas in between. I would need a list where each entry is in a new line with no commas. Is that possible your way?

Comment: It's a different question now, but `Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x).join("\n")` should turn this into a string of numbers joined by `\n`.

Comment: @spender Thats it. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list)
y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps)
z= 5 //the number of steps
let output=[]
for(let i=x;i<z;i++){
  console.log(i*y)
  output.push(i*y)
}
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [];

let x = 0;
let y = 20;
let z = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < z * y; i+= y) {
  arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```